# Copying all keys in Redis database using MIGRATE

Tags: redis

Is it possible to copy all keys from one Redis instance to another remote instance using `MIGRATE`? I've tried `COPY`, `REPLACE` and `KEYS` without any luck. Each time I get a `NOKEY` response. If I use any of the `MIGRATE` commands with a single key it works.

Examples:

```
MIGRATE my.redis 6379 "*" 0 5000 REPLACE // NOKEY
MIGRATE my.redis 6379 "*" 0 5000 COPY // NOKEY
MIGRATE my.redis 6379 "" 0 5000 KEYS * // NOKEY

MIGRATE my.redis 6379 "" 0 5000 KEYS test // OK
```

Answer (score 23):

This is an improvement on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37305332/2639936) provided by [@ezain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270262/ezain) since I am unable to post comments. The command uses the correct redis syntax for processing batches of keys, but the arguments to `xargs` result in the command being called once for every key instead of just once with all the keys included (which means it'll take much more time to complete than is necessary). The following will be much faster in all cases:

`redis-cli --raw KEYS '*' | xargs redis-cli MIGRATE my.redis 6379 "" 0 5000 KEYS`

If the destination is password protected:

- `redis-cli --raw KEYS '*' | xargs redis-cli MIGRATE my.redis 6379 "" 0 5000 AUTH password-here KEYS`

Comment: What if the remote destination instance asks for a password?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include example for password protected destination.

Answer (score 7):

try run in your shell

```
redis-cli keys '*' | xargs -I '{}' redis-cli migrate my.redis 6379 "" 0 5000 KEYS '{}'
```

Comment: This works but constrains me to copy data from only the default database `0`

Comment: `redis-cli -n 2 keys '*' | xargs -I '{}' redis-cli -n 2 migrate my.redis 6379 "" 3 5000 KEYS '{}'`
to copy from default redis db 2 to my.redis db 3

Comment: How to specify password/auth for the destination Redis server?

Comment: What if the remote destination instance asks for a password?

Answer (score 1):

For a big DBs with a lot of keys it's better to use `--scan` instead of `keys`, to avoid Redis lock on `KEYS` command:

```
redis-cli --scan | xargs redis-cli MIGRATE my.redis 6379 "" 0 5000 KEYS
```

Not really related to the question, but in case someone will need it: Redis does not support `MIGRATE` with a password before 3.0. After 3.0, you can add `AUTH` parameter to check the permission:

```
MIGRATE 192.168.0.33 6379 "" 0 5000 AUTH mypassword KEYS user:{info}:age
```

Comment: This is authenticating on the local instance I suppose? How do you send password for the destination redis host ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on non-managed¹ redis instances, the most ideal way would probably to run the target instance as a replica temporarly and then disable (after all data is copied) the replication.

see the [REPLICAOF](https://redis.io/commands/replicaof) command in redis. how to apply it (all commands on the target instance):

initiate the replication: `$ replicaof source_hostname_or_ip source_port`

after everything is done: `$ replicaof no one`

If you can't use this command¹ then you can try this script on the digital ocean blog: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-redis-data-to-a-digitalocean-managed-database#step-3-%E2%80%94-building-the-migration-script

################

¹ - managed services often restrict the usage of this command see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html) or [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-redis-data-to-a-digitalocean-managed-database#things-to-consider-when-migrating-redis-data-to-a-managed-database).

Answer (score -3):

I'm not advocating using this, but I tried all of these examples, and many others and did not work. I ended up doing it myself in PHP, so maybe this will help someone else who is stuck.

```
<?php 

$redisSource = new Redis();
$redisSource->connect('1.2.3.4', 6379);
$redisSource->auth('password');

$redisTarget = new Redis();
$redisTarget->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

foreach($redisSource->keys('*') as $key) {
    $redisTarget->set($key, $redisSource->get($key));
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't consider keys metadata like TTL

Comment: while this solution is not very "liked", it's the only way I have found so far to copy data **from a newer** version of redis **to an older** (looking at you, out of date Alpine repo). Otherwise you always get checksum/version errors