# Fastest way to copy 35GB of redis from one instance to another (in Azure standard)

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

We have two Azure Redis instances on Azure.  The source is on "standard" setting in Azure.  We need to copy all 35GB from a standard build to a premium build (not migrate).

What is the best method? The data should be static. You cannot export the data in standard, you cannot shard either. We have maxed out the size, and need to move to one that supports sharding.

Comment: Do you have access to `dump.rdb` file?

Comment: We do not have access to that file.

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it out

Comment: Could you scale the cache to premium? You would gain access to export then. Depending on your app's architecture, you could also avoid export/import by scaling the first cache and not having to change your app at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Editing config file

In target Redis's config file set

```
slaveof sourceIP sourcePort
slave-read-only no
```

It will efficiently replicate source db into your new one by transmitting RDB file. Then you can comment out these lines and shut down source instance. Note, that old keys in target instance are not preserved and not rewritten.

### 2. [CONFIG SET](https://redis.io/commands/config-set) command

Will not help you on this, sad story.

> 127.0.0.1:6371> CONFIG SET slaveof "localhost 6370"
>   (error) ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: slaveof

### 3. [MIGRATE](https://redis.io/commands/migrate) command

```
MIGRATE remotehost remoteport "" 0 5000 COPY KEYS *
```

Will not work either. But there is a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42686861/78569

> redis-cli --raw KEYS '*' | xargs redis-cli MIGRATE my.redis 6379 "" 0 5000 KEYS

(please upvote that guy, if you used it)

### 4. Shell scripting

Here's a script that pipes `KEYS` output into `MIGRATE` and adds some other features: https://gist.github.com/nicStuff/ee7feb8eed00174a46db42812545b403

### 5. RDB download

You can download RDB dump with Redis protocol even if you don't have access to the file on server:

```
redis-cli -h <host> -p <port> --rdb /path/to/local/copy/dump.rdb
```

Comment: will try out 5th option. i have linux redis running on some server who's data i needed to copy to my redis which is running on windows 10. let's see the result